# Sending email via specific email provider / Infusionsoft via C# SDK

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I would like to understand better process of sending emails via Infusionsoft email service provide.

For example I've found this piece of code on internet that shows example of sending the email via PHP:

```
 <?php
 echo "Hello World! <br/>";
 include_once('iSDK/src/isdk.php');
 //require_once"iSDK/src/isdk.php";
 $myApp = new iSDK();
 // Test Connnection
 if ($myApp->cfgCon("connectionName"))
 {
  echo "Connected...";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Not Connected...";
 }

  $myApp->sendEmail('conList','marif252@gmail.com','arif.liaqat@yahoo.com', 'ccAddresses', 'bccAddresses', 'contentType', 'subject', 'htmlBody', 'txtBody');

 ?>
```

However, I wasn't able to find anything on C# matter... Has anyone else worked with this before that could show me an example on how it's done?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)